# I have a Pandas dataframe, for each group of rows I need to reverse the order of a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

The current dataframe is already in order of groups in column A. Column C is just a sequence 1 to n

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | x | 1 |
| Group 1 | y | 2 |
| Group 1 | z | 3 |
| Group 2 | w | 1 |
| Group 2 | x | 2 |
| Group 2 | y | 3 |
| Group 2 | z | 4 |

I need to reverse column C for each group so that the dataframe looks like this:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Group 1 | x | 3 |
| Group 1 | y | 2 |
| Group 1 | z | 1 |
| Group 2 | w | 4 |
| Group 2 | x | 3 |
| Group 2 | y | 2 |
| Group 2 | z | 1 |

I've tried to group the dataframe but I need to get back from the grouped dataframe to a dataframe.
This works to reverse Column C but I'm not sure how to get it back into the dataframe or if there is a way to do this without grouping:

```
df = df.groupby('Column A', sort=False, group_keys=True).apply(lambda row: row['Column C'][::-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If need range `N` to `1` use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) with `ascending=False)` parameter:

```
df['Column C'] = df.groupby('Column A').cumcount(ascending=False).add(1)
```

Your solution for change order with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['Column C'] = df.groupby('Column A')['Column C'].transform(lambda x: x.to_numpy()[::-1])
```